# How to push array to the JSON element

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am reading a json file like this:

```
 $path = storage_path() . "/userexam.json"; 
 $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true); 

 foreach($json as $js){
       dd($js);
 }
```

And the result of `dd($js)` which shows every single element of json goes like this:

```
array:13 [▼
  "_id" => "d4466d06-3d47-41c4-aa5e-664752d84004"
  "user" => "0123456789"
  "exam" => "First Exam"
  "total_time_in_minute" => 8640
  "number_of_question" => 17
  "start_time" => array:1 [▶]
  "questions" => array:17 [▶]
  "last_question" => 10
  "is_finished" => false
  "result" => null
  "updated_at" => array:1 [▶]
  "created_at" => array:1 [▶]
  "score" => null
]
```

As you can see now the `result` has 21 items in array.

So how can I push this data into the array?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks.

And now I need to add another key value after the `result`, which goes like this:

```
{
      "name":"niloo", 
      "phone_number":"0123456789", 
      
      "number_of_questions_test":15, 
      "number_of_answer_test":1, 
      "number_of_true_test":2, 
      "number_of_false_test":3, 
      "exam_score_test":4, 
      
      "number_of_questions_desc":15, 
      "number_of_answer_desc":5, 
      "number_of_true_desc":6, 
      "number_of_false_desc":7, 
      "exam_score_desc":8, 
      
      "number_of_questions_func":15,
      "number_of_answer_func":9, 
      "number_of_true_func":10, 
      "number_of_false_func":11, 
      "exam_score_func":12, 
      
      "user_score":13, 
      "winner_score":14, 
      "user_rank":15, 
      "num_competitor":16, 
      "final_score":true 
      
}
```

So the final data would be like this:

```
array:13 [▼
      "_id" => "d4466d06-3d47-41c4-aa5e-664752d84004"
      "user" => "0123456789"
      "exam" => "First Exam"
      "total_time_in_minute" => 8640
      "number_of_question" => 17
      "start_time" => array:1 [▶]
      "questions" => array:17 [▶]
      "last_question" => 10
      "is_finished" => false
      "result" => array:21 [▶]
      "updated_at" => array:1 [▶]
      "created_at" => array:1 [▶]
      "score" => null
    ]
```

As you can see the `result` now has 21 items in it.

So how can I do that?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Comment: _"So the final data would be like this:"_ Like *what*?

Comment: @kmoser Sorry please check out the question again

Comment: How is your intended final data different from your starting data? They look exactly the same.

Comment: @kmoser At the first data `result` is `null`. But I need to append the new json file to the `result` value. So the `result` in last data won't be empty anymore

Comment: You wrote: `"result" => null` and `As you can see now the result has 21 items in array.` It seems you are contradicting yourself. I suggest you make one final edit to your question to make it very clear what your data looks like, and what your intended result should look like. Without a clearly written question, you will likely not get the help you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search index of array element with "result" key and use array_slice():

```
$array = array(
  'zero'  => '0',
  'one'   => '1',
  'result'   => '2',
  'three' => '3',
);
$index=array_search("result",array_keys($array));
$res = array_slice($array, 0, $index, true) +
    array("my_key" => "my_value") +
    array_slice($array, $index, count($array) - 1, true) ;
print_r($res);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [zero] => 0
    [one] => 1
    [result] => 2
    [my_key] => my_value
    [three] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you use it like that:

```
$test1=[ // jsondecode array
    'data1'=>[
        'id'=>1,
        ],
    'data2'=>'asd'
    ];
    
$result=[ //result array
    'id'=>1,
    'name'=>'asd'
    ];
    $test1['result']=$result; // value set in put array or push value in array
    
print_r($test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way array to json in php. Hope this will help you to understand about json.

```
 $arr = array('ABC' => 'Eleven', 
            'DEF' => 'Finn', 
            'GHI' => 'Dustin', 
            'KLM' => 'Will'); 
echo json_encode($arr)."\n";
```